# flexible array, optimal space, indexing error

Tags: c, arrays, algorithm, testing

I am implementing a flexible array in C. All ideas are based upon this small [Paper](https://cs.uwaterloo.ca/research/tr/1999/09/CS-99-09.pdf).
My error is with the indexing operation. Been hacking away for too long to admit. Asking for knowledgable minds and eyes.

**Overview**:
The data structure consists of 1 flat index block which holds pointers to the data blocks. Each data block has size 2^(k/2). Where k is the leading set bit. So when I search for element "i", k is log_2(i+1).

```
index = { 
    [0], -> [0]
    [2],  -> [0,1]
    [2],  -> [0,1]
    [3],  -> [0,1,2,3]
    [4],  -> [0,1,2,3]
    ....}
```

The size of each data block is determined by the "super block" it is clustered into. Where a super block is  made up of data blocks with the same size. So. index 1,2 are in the same super block (super block 1). While 0 (super block 0), and index 3 (superblock 2) are not.

You end up with each superblock having 2^(floor(k/2)) data blocks, and each of those data blocks has size 2^(ceil(k/2)).

**The Problem**
When r = a power of 2 the index skips over what is should be.
Like when I search for 3 it should be `index [2][0]`, instead its `index[3][0]`.
Why does this happen? any way to avoid it? Is there an "off by 1" error I'm not seeing??

**The Code**
Here is the single main function [testcase](https://gist.github.com/3975639), it's clear and simple, and fails when trying to get element at index 3;

The simplified code for the locating index i is this:

```
/* Edited from the actual test case for extra clarity */
/* all vars int */
r= i+1
k = first_set_bit(r) - 1;   // ex: r = 5, 5 = "00000101"b so k is (3-1) = 2

b = first_subset_of_r(floor(k/2)); // floor(k/2) bits of r immediately after first set; 
e = last_subset_of_r(ceil(k/2); // last ceil(k/2) bits of r 
p = (1 << k) -1 ; // 2^k -1
// Index supposed to be found with. . .
return index[p+b][e];
```

Here is some real output, of first printing the array's contents by index and data block, then the output of 4 trys into the index

The first part dumps the 2d array, where the number before the bar is the index of the index block, and the part after is the elements contained in the array that the index block points to. all arrays are zero indexed.

```
[clemensm@gaia:23]> ./a.out 
Index block |  element number (Not it's index!)
0 | 0   
1 | 1   2   
2 | 3   4   
3 | 5   6   
4 | 7   8   9   10  
5 | 11  12  13  14  
6 | 15  16  17  18  
7 | 19  20  21  22  
8 | 23  24  25  26  
9 | 27  28  29  30  
10 | 31  32  33  34  35  36  37  38  
11 | 39  40  41  42  43  44  45  46  
12 | 47  48  49  50  51  52  53  54  
13 | 55  56  57  58  59  60  61  62  
14 | 63  64  65  66  67  68  69  70  
15 | 71  72  73  74  75  76  77  78  
16 | 79  80  81  82  83  84  85  86  
17 | 87  88  89  90  91  92  93  94  
18 | 95  96  97  98  99  100 101 102 
19 | 103 104 105 106 107 108 109 110 
Finished element dump

Trying to get 0
R: [1]b
k/2=[0], Ceil(k,2)=[0]
K: [0] is the leading 1 bit
B: [0]
E: [0]
P: [0] data blocks prior to our superblock
p+b,e : [0,0] 

Trying to get 1
R: [10]b
k/2=[0], Ceil(k,2)=[1]
K: [1] is the leading 1 bit
B: [0]
E: [0]
P: [1] data blocks prior to our superblock
p+b,e : [1,0] 

Trying to get 2
R: [11]b
k/2=[0], Ceil(k,2)=[1]
K: [1] is the leading 1 bit
B: [0]
E: [1]
P: [1] data blocks prior to our superblock
p+b,e : [1,1] 

Trying to get 3
R: [100]b
k/2=[1], Ceil(k,2)=[1]
K: [2] is the leading 1 bit
B: [0]
E: [0]
P: [3] data blocks prior to our superblock
p+b,e : [3,0] 
a.out: test_array.c:81: main: Assertion `get_index(3)==3' failed.
Abort (core dumped)
```

Comment: That looks like an [off by one error](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Off-by-one_error)

Comment: It's plausible, yet I've already tried hunting that sort of error down and no luck so far. Every combo, whether it was in the for loop index creation, or fsb being 1 or 0 indexed, I've tried.

Comment: The output should be 0, then 1, then 2 3 right?

Comment: Yes, the initial part of the test case makes sure the elements are in the right spot, as well as visually showing what I mean by 2^(k/2) elements in a data_block.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just for the search engines and clearity, the paper name: `Resizable Arrays in Optimal Time and Space`
As far as I see it from the paper, you can make a very basic experience here. Even if it is a nice looking paper, there can be mistakes.

The locate algorithm is clearly wrong. Line 3 claiming to calculate the number of data blocks prior to `SB_k` can not work this way. You see this already in your example above.

I suggest to find out the formula by yourself and continue reading afterwards.

My analysis suggests this formula:

```
p = 2^(k/2 + 1) - 2 + (k mod 2) * 2^(k/2) # "/" indicates integer division
```

Sample code:

```
int max = 20;
for (int k = 0; k < max; k++)
    System.out.println("k=" + k + " - data blocks: " + Math.pow(2, k/2) + " - data blocks size: " + Math.pow(2, Math.ceil(k/2.0)));
System.out.println();

for (int i = 0; i < max; i++) {
    String r = Integer.toBinaryString(i + 1);
    int k = r.length() - 1;
    String b_bin = r.substring(1, 1 + k/2);
    int b = Integer.parseInt("0" + b_bin, 2);
    String e_bin = r.substring((int)Math.ceil(k / 2.0));
    int e = Integer.parseInt("0" + e_bin, 2);
    int p = (1 << (k/2 + 1)) - 2 + (k & 1) * (1 << (k/2));
    int db = p + b;
    System.out.println("i=" + i + ", r=" + r + ", k=" + k + ", b_bin=" + b_bin + ", b=" + b + ", e_bin=" + e_bin + ", e=" + e + ", p=" + p + ", db=" + db);
}
```

Sample results:

```
k=0 - data blocks: 1.0 - data blocks size: 1.0
k=1 - data blocks: 1.0 - data blocks size: 2.0
k=2 - data blocks: 2.0 - data blocks size: 2.0
k=3 - data blocks: 2.0 - data blocks size: 4.0
k=4 - data blocks: 4.0 - data blocks size: 4.0
k=5 - data blocks: 4.0 - data blocks size: 8.0
k=6 - data blocks: 8.0 - data blocks size: 8.0
k=7 - data blocks: 8.0 - data blocks size: 16.0
k=8 - data blocks: 16.0 - data blocks size: 16.0
k=9 - data blocks: 16.0 - data blocks size: 32.0
k=10 - data blocks: 32.0 - data blocks size: 32.0
k=11 - data blocks: 32.0 - data blocks size: 64.0
k=12 - data blocks: 64.0 - data blocks size: 64.0
k=13 - data blocks: 64.0 - data blocks size: 128.0
k=14 - data blocks: 128.0 - data blocks size: 128.0
k=15 - data blocks: 128.0 - data blocks size: 256.0
k=16 - data blocks: 256.0 - data blocks size: 256.0
k=17 - data blocks: 256.0 - data blocks size: 512.0
k=18 - data blocks: 512.0 - data blocks size: 512.0
k=19 - data blocks: 512.0 - data blocks size: 1024.0

i=0, r=1, k=0, b_bin=, b=0, e_bin=1, e=1, p=0, db=0
i=1, r=10, k=1, b_bin=, b=0, e_bin=0, e=0, p=1, db=1
i=2, r=11, k=1, b_bin=, b=0, e_bin=1, e=1, p=1, db=1
i=3, r=100, k=2, b_bin=0, b=0, e_bin=00, e=0, p=2, db=2
i=4, r=101, k=2, b_bin=0, b=0, e_bin=01, e=1, p=2, db=2
i=5, r=110, k=2, b_bin=1, b=1, e_bin=10, e=2, p=2, db=3
i=6, r=111, k=2, b_bin=1, b=1, e_bin=11, e=3, p=2, db=3
i=7, r=1000, k=3, b_bin=0, b=0, e_bin=00, e=0, p=4, db=4
i=8, r=1001, k=3, b_bin=0, b=0, e_bin=01, e=1, p=4, db=4
i=9, r=1010, k=3, b_bin=0, b=0, e_bin=10, e=2, p=4, db=4
i=10, r=1011, k=3, b_bin=0, b=0, e_bin=11, e=3, p=4, db=4
i=11, r=1100, k=3, b_bin=1, b=1, e_bin=00, e=0, p=4, db=5
i=12, r=1101, k=3, b_bin=1, b=1, e_bin=01, e=1, p=4, db=5
i=13, r=1110, k=3, b_bin=1, b=1, e_bin=10, e=2, p=4, db=5
i=14, r=1111, k=3, b_bin=1, b=1, e_bin=11, e=3, p=4, db=5
i=15, r=10000, k=4, b_bin=00, b=0, e_bin=000, e=0, p=6, db=6
i=16, r=10001, k=4, b_bin=00, b=0, e_bin=001, e=1, p=6, db=6
i=17, r=10010, k=4, b_bin=00, b=0, e_bin=010, e=2, p=6, db=6
i=18, r=10011, k=4, b_bin=00, b=0, e_bin=011, e=3, p=6, db=6
i=19, r=10100, k=4, b_bin=01, b=1, e_bin=100, e=4, p=6, db=7
```

edit: More details about the way to the formula

How to get the formula (I suggest to read every step and think if you can continue by yourself, if not continue to tread):
The paper says: `"When superblock SB_k is fully allocated, it consists of 2^floor(k/2) data blocks"`

If we want the number of data blocks prior to SB_k, we have to sum over all of them:

```
p = sum from i=0 to k-1 over 2^floor(i/2)
```

We could use this now, this is a clear for loop statement. But lets make it a single calculation.
If you think about the sum, it sums up every 2^i two times because of the floor. This is true for all even k, because the sum max is uneven then, hence we have `floor((k-2)/2) = floor((k-1)/2)`.
For odd k, we have one single number, we have to care about this separately.

So, we have now:

```
(2 * sum from i=0 to floor((k-2)/2) over 2^i) + (k mod 2)*2^k/2
```

(make some examples for k=6,7,8 if you need some more details)

Now, we can clearly get rid of the sum, because we know that `sum from i=0 to n over 2^i = 2^(n+1) - 1` (this is a basic math/cs proof. You can clearly see the correctness from the binary representation). We use this formula to get:

```
2 * (2^(floor((k-2)/2) + 1) - 1) + (k mod 2)*2^k/2
```

Now, we can multiply by the 2, modify the exponent and we are finished:

```
2^(floor(k/2) + 1) - 2 + (k mod 2)*2^k/2
```

I hope, this helps.

Comment: I'm impressed. Could you explain the intuition, or direction you took to solve it. For instance, the minus 2 in your answer?

Comment: As a young student I trust such respected publications, and I find it discouraging that I couldn't find any prior analysis such as yours showing its faults. Maybe my implementation differs from the authors' projection, but still, are these types of issues common?

Comment: "are the types of issues common" well, define common. I have seen some papers with errors in the implementation part. The reasons are quite trivial: it is is only theoretical done, different versions which are mixed, or noone cares about it. Even reviewers will take care more about the theoretical part as the implementation. As a student, realize that the more people claiming something, it only increase the probability to be right. In doubt, check the arguments and conclusions yourself (assuming, that you trust yourself). In general, this is one of the keys to make your way through science.

Comment: about explanation: i will edit my post later (most probably at the weekend). In general there are 2 ways: Do it theoretically, or make examples and find patterns.

Comment: Nice work. As an optimization to the formula: You are using `(k mod 2)*2^k/2` to include `2^k/2` if `k` is odd (multiply by 1), but not if it is even (multiply by 0). We can replace it by `2^k/2 & -(k & 1)`. This achieves the same thing, without the modulo and multiplication. For _even_ it masks by `0`, while for _odd_ it masks by `~0` (all bits set). `-(k & 1)` makes all bits equal to the LSB, as found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54429850/543814). I'm kind of hoping the formula can be further optimized...