# Setting all Bits to the Least Significant Bit

Tags: c, binary, bit-manipulation

If I have a `x` of type `int`, how can I get the value of `x`'s LSB and set all of the other bits in the number to that LSB?

I've been messing around with bitwise and logical operators for a little bit (no pun intended) and I understand how they function.

The shift operators `x >> 3` and `x << 3` shift the bits of x three spaces left and right respectively, and I know we can use operators like `^` `|` and `&` for messing around with manipulating bits. I'm having trouble understanding the logic for this particular problem.

EDIT: The operators which we are allowed to use for this are ! ~ & ^ | + << >>

Comment: Are you constrained to bitwise operations only? If not, for a 2's complement system it would be `-(x & 1)`.

Comment: @Eugene Sh. Yes, and we are also can't use the subtraction operator. Your solution is very elegant and makes more sense from just looking at it, but how could it be done without that subtraction operator?

Comment: @BenJenkins: You must specify which operations may be used. Additionally, what is known about the type of `x`? Is it an integer type? Signed? Unsigned? Floating-point? Complex?

Comment: @BenJenkins If you get the size of x, by `sizeof` or just knowing it's size, you could hold the LSB in a variable like @PSkocik did, and then shift by It's size, each time changing the new LSB to whatever was the LSB.

Comment: @Eric Postpischil Gotcha, we're allowed to use ! ~ & ^ | + << >> and `x` is an int.

Comment: If the C implementation is known to use two’s complement, then `~(x&1) + 1` is a solution. If it is not known to use two’s complement, I suspect there is no solution, as it is necessary to use some conditional operator (such as `? :`) or control flow (`if…else`). because the listed operations by themselves may be inadequate. Except it may be possible to devise an expression that effectively “tests” for one’s complement or sign-and-magnitude and produces the desired result.

Comment: Thanks @Eric Postpischil, your solution works with my restrictions, but I'm still a little confused in how ~(x&1) + 1 can take the LSB and set every other bit in the int to that LSB. When I look at your solution, I think to take x (say "5", 0101), compare it to 0001 using & (which gives us 0001), negate it (yielding 1110) and then adding 0001. Why wouldn't this produce 11101?

Comment: Are you sure that LSB in your problem is not the least set bit not the bit 0. Otherwise the it is too trivial and easy.

Comment: I'm inclined to agree with @EricPostpischil that there is no strictly-conforming solution to the question as posed that can be given in the form of a single expression.  It would be different if `x` had an unsigned type, if we could make assumptions about the representation or type `int` and behavior of integer overflows, or if we had other allowed operators (`*`, for example).

Comment: @BenJenkins: 1110 plus 0001 is 1111.

Answer (score 5):

Very literally:

```
type x /*=some value*/;
_Bool lsb = x&1;
x = lsb ? ~(type)0 : (type)0;
```

Optimizing compilers on 2's complement architectures make it branch-less
and equivalent to:

```
 type x /*=some value*/;
_Bool lsb = x&1;
 x = -lsb;
```

(or `-(x&1)` without the intermediary `lsb` variable.)

https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/2NXFpS

Comment: Thanks, after looking into what you're saying this makes a little more sense.

Comment: I do not think it so easy. Usually when someone asks about finding the LSB it means lowest set bit not the bit zero

Comment: @P__J__ Well, then it'd degenerate to set all bits to 1 if x is nonzero.

Answer (score 0):

if (x & 1) {x = 4294967295 } else { x = 0 }.
In other words if x is odd the LSB is 1 so set x to the biggest possible 32 bit unsigned integer (all bits set to 1), otherwise if x is even the LSB is zero, so set x to be zero. But wait, it is a signed integer, setting all the bits to 1 would mean the signed bit is set. So change that to be:
if (x & 1) { x = -1 } else { x = 0 }. As commented by Eugene one can then just use -(x & 1).

Comment: I do not think it so easy. Usually when someone asks about finding the LSB it means lowest set bit not the bit zero

Comment: @P__J__ *That* would be easy, as per your definition it will be always `1`. No, the LSB is the bit 0 by definition.

Comment: @P__J__ I think the question implies the LSB in the signed int? Perhaps the question needs clarification?

Comment: No @EugeneSh. - the number 01001100 will be in this case 11111011

Comment: @P__J__ The op is just asking to have `0` in this case.

Comment: @EugeneSh. plus (as only arithmetic operation) is allowed so I it points to my understanding of the problem

Comment: -2147483648 is not all ones in 32-bit two’s complement (1000…000), one’s complement (not representable), or sign-and-magnitude (also not representable).

Comment: @Eric Postpischil Thanks for spotting my mistake, I corrected my answer.

Answer (score -2):

You all assume - but recently I was helping examining students and the the question - find the LSB or value of the LSB meant the lowest bit set in the number. It make a bit more sense making the task less trivial and obvious.

in this case:

to get value of the LSB - `z & (~z+1)`

```
 z = ~(z & (~z+1));
```

Comment: Surely simlicity over complexity would be best. If the questioner is unclear the student is not at fault.

Comment: @Peter *Surely simlicity* it is rather **Surely triviality**

Comment: Trivial is good, if all code were trivial we would all be triviallionaires.

Comment: Even the title says "least significant bit". What exactly makes you assume, that any other bit than bit 0 could be meant? "Least significant bit" means, that the value changes the least, when you toggle that bit, compared to any other bit.

Comment: @Ctx: When discussing a numeral such as 2.37•10^8, 7 is said to be the least significant digit. Similarly, we can ask what is the least significant bit of a number (the least non-zero digit in its binay expression) rather than the least significant bit in a format (the lowest position). But that would not make sense in this context; if a number is not zero, its least significant bit is 1, so the problem would ask us to produce 0 for 0 and ~0 for anything else, which does not seem like the intent of question.

Comment: @EricPostpischil as I understand it they want all set except the LAB of the original number